# MongoDB + Node JS + Role Based Access Control (RBAC)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, rbac

**Am currently learning MEAN** stack, developing a simple TODO's app and want to implement Role Based Access Control (RBAC) for that. How do i set up roles & permission on MongoDB.

I want 3 roles (roles may look funny but this is purely to learn) :

- GOD
- SUPER HERO
- MAN

**GOD** - similar to super admin, can do anything in the application. C,R,U,D permissions for TODO's and for other users too. Can Create a TODO & assign it to any SUPER HERO or MAN directly. Update or Delete either a TODO or a User at any point in time.

**SUPER HERO** - similar to admin, has super power to do anything on his personal Data - C,R,U,D for TODO's. Can't create any users. Can only Read & add comments for TODO's created by GOD & assigned to him/her.

**MAN** - Can only Read and add comments to TODO's assigned to him/her.

To sum it up :

`GOD - C,R,U,D [Global Level]
SUPER HERO - C,R,U,D [Private] + R,U [Assigned to him]
MAN - R,U [Assigned to him]`

I understand that i need to have USERS & ROLES collections. Where ROLES inturn should have PERMISSIONS etc. How do i wire them all ?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

*I like names given to roles - **GOD, SUPER HERO & MAN**, easy to understand.*

As you are using MEAN stack and much of routes validation happens on `node`, i would prefer keeping roles table simple.

**Roles :**

```
{
_id : 1,
name : GOD,
golbalPerms : true
},
{
_id : 2,
name : SUPER HERO,
privatePerms : true
},
{
_id : 3,
name : MAN
}
```

**Users :**

```
{
_id : 111,
name : Jesus,
roleId : 1
},
{
_id : 222,
name : BatMan,
roleId : 2
},
{
_id : 333,
name : Jack,
roleId : 3
}
```

When user logs in and sending `user` object back to client, make sure to replace `roleId` with corresponding `role` object from DB.

**Coming to code on Node JS :**

By completely understanding your usecase we can divide them into following methods -

- CreateUser
- CreateTodo
- DeleteTodo
- ReadTodo
- UpdateTodo
- CommentTodo
- AssignTodo

Lets go step by step, **CreateUser**.

Routes code snippet :

```
app.all('/users', users.requiresLogin);

// Users Routes
app.route('/users')
    .post(users.hasPerms('globalPerms'), users.create);
```

In your Controller you can validate based on the input `globalPerms`, if validated allow to create user by calling `next()` else `return` with corresponding error message.

Now **CreateTodo** && **DeleteTodo** :

Both of them pretty much work on same logic with a small trick.

Routes code snippet :

```
app.all('/todos', users.requiresLogin);

// Users Routes
app.route('/todos')
    .post(users.hasPerms('globalPerms','privatePerms'), todos.create);
    .delete(users.hasPerms('globalPerms','privatePerms'), todos.delete);
```

For creating a Todo, `globalPerms` are with **GOD** & `privatePerms` are with **SUPER HERO**, both of them can be allowed.

Trick here will be in `todos.delete` method, just ensure `user.id === todos.createById` else SUPER HERO may go on to delete Todos created by GOD.

**ReadTodo** :

When a **TODO** is created it should  have a `createById` stored likewise when a **TODO** is assigned to someone then `assignedTo` and `assignedBy` should be recorded too.

This makes lot of other operations easy to handle.

`user.role.globalPerms` - give GOD all TODO's data.

`user.role.privatePerms` - give TODO's either createdBy him/her or assigned to him/her.

`user.role.globalPerms === undefined && user.role.privatePerms  === undefined` - its MAN and give TODO's which are only assignedTo him.

**UpdateTodo & CommentTodo** :

This is exact replica of what ReadTODO does so DIY

Last one, **AssignTodo** :

Simple one, `loggedInUser.id === todos.createdById` then he can assign it to anyone.

Two things to keep in mind here :

1. As assigning part mostly happens on your UI (Angular) front, i have given that approach of checking `loggedInUser.id === todos.createdById`. Logged in user any ways will see all TODO's by read operation and can assign it to anyone he/she likes.
2. Make sure a **SUPER HERO** can only assign a TODO to himself or other SUPER HERO or to a MAN but not to GOD. How you show Assign to options on UI front is out of scope of this question. This is just a heads up.

Hope this was clear.

**NOTE : There was no necessity to give permissions to MAN in Roles collection & we managed all possible operations with out that.**

Comment: That was clean n best possible solution I could have asked for with out using any 3rd party module. Thanks :)

Comment: Is it bad to query twice in each request, for example, first querying on `Roles` collection in middleware, and then querying in another collection?

Answer (score 2):

This is a very broad question which can be solved in many ways.

You have added that you are using MEAN stack therefore I'll restrict my question to that.

One thing that you haven't included in the whole question is what kind of authentication architecture are you using. Let's say you are using token based authentication, generally people these days use it.

We have 3 types of users. 
You have different options available to differentiate between type of tokens as well.

1. Different Collection (mongoDB) or Redis sets where they will be stored
2. The encrypted token will have type of the user as well  etc.. (This will come in handy if you don't need to store tokens on the backend, you can just decrypt and check)

   - It will completely depend on use case.

Now, before allowing any user's entry to user specific route make sure that you are checking the token first.

Example

```
app.post('/godlevelroute', godtokencheck, callrouteandfunction);
app.post('/superherolevelroute', superheroroute, callrouteandfunction);
```

You must send token in header from angular and then you can take the data out from the header and then you can check if that specific user has permission to go through that route or not.

Let's say a god level user is logged in then he'll have the godleveltoken with him and we'll check that first before allowing him to access that route or else you can just show error message.

This can be your sample token checking function on server end

```
function checkToken(req, res, next) {
var token = req.headers['accesstoken']; //access token from header
//now depending upon which system you are following you can run a check
};
```

Node Module Suggestion : https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken

Now coming to frontend part. You are using angular based on what you have written, you can intercept the token before showing any page.

You can go through this blog to get a pictorial representation of what I have tried to explain. [Click Here](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/token-based-authentication-with-angularjs-nodejs--cms-22543)

Answer (score 1):

Possible approach-> have role embedded in user collection/schema:
users document shall have the following:

```
{
    _id : "email@mail.com",
    name: "lorem ipsum",
    role: "MAN"
}
```

As far as your post describes, only god can make and assign TODOs. 
Roles Collection may hold the following:

```
{
    _id : "MAN",
    globalPerm: [],
    privatePerm: [],
    assignedPerm: ["r","u"],
},
{
    _id : "SUPER_HERO",
    globalPerm: [],
    privatePerm: ["c","r","u","d"],
    assignedPerm: ["c","r","u","d"],
},
{
    _id : "GOD",
    globalPerm: ["c","r","u","d"],
    privatePerm: ["c","r","u","d"],
    assignedPerm: ["c","r","u","d"],
}
```

**Node JS Middlewares**
After getting correct permission values for a user, you might want to use middlewares.
Sample express HTTP request route:

```
app.post('/updateTodo', permissions.check('privatePerm', 'c'), function (req, res) {
 // do stuff
```

};

permissions.check is called before actually executing function body to update TODO.

Hence if a user tries to update a todo, it will first verify the corresponding permissions.